# how to increase Gwt Horizontal Panel table height

Tags: gwt

Trying to use the following code to set the table height of a Horizontal panel. Is there any thing wrong with the below code. When i run it in fire bug mode of fire fox came to know that the height is applying to 'TD' element of HTML, but not to 'TABLE' element of HTML.

```
setCellHeight(resetButton, "400")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the setCellHeight() method applies to cell inside a table a not the table, so it is normal that the height is applying to the 'TD' element and not the 'TABLE' element of HTML.

What you can do to set the height of the table is use the addStyleName() method to set the height with the css.

In the java code :

```
table.addStyleName("table");
```

In the css:

```
 .table{
   height: 400px;
   /*other wished styling*/
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I belive you may be looking for [`setHeight()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#setHeight%28java.lang.String%29)

```
horizontalPanel.setHeight("400px")
```